History of private sponsorship of GM titles
According to this chess.com article "Jeanne Sinquefield Offers Historic $100,000 Awards To New Female Grandmasters In U.S"

In a groundbreaking initiative to support women's chess, Saint Louis Chess Club has announced $100,000 awards to U.S. female players achieving the grandmaster title by July 4, 2029.
Jeanne Cairns Sinquefield, co-founder of the Saint Louis Chess Club, announced the Cairns Chess Queens Award during the opening of the Cairns Cup on Thursday. She will present a $100,000 check to the first five American women who achieve the title of grandmaster in the next five years

The only other case like this I know of is British financier, Jim Slater, who in 1972 made a similar offer to English male players to achieve the GM title.

A few months later, in an endeavour to help our young players, Jim Slater offered on behalf of The Slater Foundation to give a prize of £5,000 (about £75,000 in today’s money) to the first British grand master and £2,500 to the next four. Over the next few years Great Britain went from having no grand masters to twenty and became one of the strongest teams of young chess players in the world.

Raymond Keene narrowly lost out on the £5,000 prize to Tony Miles who went on to dominate the English chess scene until he was pushed aside by Nigel Short.
Clearly this kind of financial incentive can make a big difference. Are there any other instances of private individuals offering these kinds of prize for gaining the GM title?

The financial incentive may work better if given as funding once 1st GM norm have been earned.   As giving to new GM don't help with the high cost of playing in enough tournaments.
